# FROM_UNIXTIME without time zone conversion?

Tags: mysql

What's the best approach to convert 0x00000009 to 1970-01-01-00:00:09?

I've tried FROM_UNIXTIME but it returns 1969-12-31 22:00:09.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp, I understand there is a time zone conversion going on.

Answer (score 2):

When time zones are a problem, try [the `CONVERT_TZ()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```sql
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(9), 'SYSTEM', '+0:00')
```

Comment: Good, thanks! It also works replacing 'SYSTEM' by '-02:00',  FROM_UNIXTIME(9), '-02:00', '+0:00'). Are there major diferences between them? Which should I prefer?

Comment: SYSTEM will always be the current system time and will ensure your code is portable. What If your time zone changes on the server due to summer time or relocation?